# Passing data between elements in UI

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, google-app-engine

I'm new to web applications and am trying to understand the best way to work with data in HTML. I'm using Appengine (Python) and have managed to load a bunch of data to the view. In the simplest form, it's a set of movie names and each name has associated details with it (e.g. year, rating etc). Now how do I pass data between the movie link and then a div where all the details will be displayed? I'll be using jQuery for some controls in my application so I'm wondering if there's a way to do data binding to controls with that?

Additionally, can anyone tell me what're the standards around this i.e. if I load all this data to the UI in one call (assuming it's not a lot of movie titles), wouldn't it make it easy for people to screen scrape this information? Or is there some obfuscation that's typically used here?

Sorry if I'm not very clear but I really am an absolute beginner with web development!

Update1:
I found the jQuery data() api. It seems like this'll work. Comments?

Update2:
Some testing later and it turns out that data() actually attaches the data to the elements rather than showing it in a div itself.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just went back and addressed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways to do it but the basic idea is to put the data in the HTML in a way that is not visibly rendered, then use Javascript to parse the HTML and pull the data out when you need it.

The easiest way on modern browsers is to use data- attributes.  These are any attribute that start with data-, and you can name the rest yourself.  For example:

```
<a href="/movie/1234" data-id="1234" data-title="Tsar Wars" data-actors="[Harryson Fjord, Carry Fischer]">Czar Wars</a>
```

In this case, the user will only see a link called "Tsar Wars" but your javascript can easily access the data- attributes to get the data it needs.  The other benefit of this approach is that jQuery will automatically make data- attributes accessible by the data() api.

Another way to do it is to have a hidden HTML list element with all your data elements in the list, but you'll have to parse this all yourself.

There's no standard obfuscation.  You'll need to obfuscate yourself on the server side, and unobfuscate in your JS.  It's not too difficult to figure out any obfuscation algorighm in js, so this is not worth your while.

If the data really is private, then you would have to architect it as to do all the processing on the server.  For example, only show tokens (like 1234), and use AJAX calls to pass the token to the server so the server can do the data processing and spit back publicly safe results to the script.